# Not able to connect to any instance on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection, instance

I am a new user of AWS. I followed the "getting started" instructions to launch an instance of EC2 and I got it to work with connecting to Windows Free Tier AMI.

But one day after I tried a couple of times with Ubuntu AMIs and it didn't launch any output console using Firefox to connect via Java (not via SSH) and tried with SSH and also didn't connect using PuTTY. Then I repeated the process with the Windows AMI to see whether the problem is due to the chosen Ubuntu AMI but it didn't work out and didn't connect to my computer although I followed the same process as in my first trial where it worked perfectly.

I don't know a lot about network configurations considering I checked security group settings to open up RDP and SSH, but no luck.

Still when launching any instance they work and run but don't connect to my PC at all.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Have you created an EC2 instance? Have you got details of a running Windows machine on the AWS infrastructure? Have you tried pinging your public IPv4 address?